# How to step into a OWIN middleware in a package?

Tags: owin, visual-studio-debugging, katana, owin.security

I have the following stack in my ASPNET 5 app startup:

```
appBuilder.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication();
// That calls
app.UseValidationEndpoint();
// That calls
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication();
// That calls
app.Use(typeof(OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware), app, options);
```

The final call adds `OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware` to the middleware pipeline, this class overrrides the `CreateHandler()` method returning a new instance of `OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler` class.

`OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler` class is the class that deals with the bearer token and that's where I'm trying to step into. The problem is that I can only set a breakpoint at the `Startup.Configure()` method, and this method runs only once when the application starts.

Even in this circutsnace I have trued to step into `OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler` using the original Katana source code that I have downloaded from CodePlex and loading appropriate symbols but for some reason the symbols won't give me information about the `OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler` class.

I really need to see what's going on inside that class, in special into the `AuthenticateCoreAsync()` method, but I don't know how to capture a request and go through the pipeline stack and get to that class as `Startup.Configure()` is only called once and in my circunstance I only have a problem when I provice a bearer token. I hope I was clear enough to get an answer :)